# Who decides and writes the on-topic and off-topic pages?

Tags: support, on-topic, off-topic

Several months ago I posted this: [On-topic and off-topic pages need to be clarified](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1506/2444), which has **NOT** yet been addressed. In the past, there have been other similar posts, for example

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1252/2444)
- **[A friendly reminder that this site comes from the Science category](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1141/2444)**
- [How can we quickly describe our site?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1197/2444)
- [What should the AI.SE Site Description be?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1430/2444)
- [The description of the site seems incorrect](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1291/2444)
- [Is it time to modify our site guidelines?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1356/2444)
- [What kind of implementation questions should be off-topic?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1081/2444)
- [How to distinguish between 'programming' and 'conceptual' questions?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1215/2444)
- [Why aren't implementation based questions welcome on this stack?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1559/2444)
- [What is in scope under the "implementation of machine learning" exclusion?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1287/2444)
- [Can questions of programming AI/NN frameworks be on-topic?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1139/2444)
- [Technical questions are not getting closed](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1279/2444)
- [Do we want easy technical questions?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15/2444)

Who writes the on-topic and off-topic pages? Can moderators change the on-topic and off-topic pages? If yes, why haven't they taken action? Who actually decides the content of the on-topic and off-topic pages?

Answer (score 1):

We had done a consensus-based edit last year: [What should the AI.SE Site Description be?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1430/what-should-the-ai-se-site-description-be).

(Essentially, a bunch of active users contributed to the thread, and then the edits were made by the active mods.  Although I was hoping for more people to participate, we had to go with the input and consensus we had at the time.)

I do think this is something that should be revisited at regular intervals, especially since we are not fully graduated as a stack, and more flexibility in terms of modifying our scope.  ("[Bend don't break](https://www.masslive.com/patriots/2017/11/the_2017_new_england_patriots.html)" is my motto!)

When we revisit again, I strongly think we should take a cue from the Data Science help page b/c they provide good advice about topic overlap between stacks: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

I also personally think we should expand our scope to reference

- Journalism (coverage of AI in the press per public perception and fact checking)
- History of AI
- Mythology of AI (portrayals of AI in popular media which informs public perception)

  and hold a referendum on other topics that contributors have chosen to answer over here, per the DS recommendation to "ask on the stack with the most users."

Comment: I was not talking about the main description of the site. I was talking about clarifying the [on-topic](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) pages. In my opinion, the on-topic page should list the specific topics, which I list in [my post](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1506/2444), which received 7 upvotes, which means that there are a lot of people that agree with the content of that post.

Comment: I agree with you that the history of AI should be on-topic, so it should be listed on the on-topic page. I think that journalism and mythology of AI can also be on-topic here, but we must be very careful: we should only accept questions that can be answered based on facts. Every question that will lead to opinions and is not philosophical should not be allowed. So, for example, a question like "Is it true that this model really obtained 95% percent accuracy on this task, as stated in this article?" or "What are the aspects of this AI portrayed in film X can currently be implemented?" are fine.