# How to go about editing past questions and answers with new $\LaTeX$ support?

Tags: discussion, editing

I just noticed that [$\LaTeX$ support has been enabled on the site](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/1641). In this meta discussion where that feature was requested, large lists of existing questions and answers that would benefit from $\LaTeX$ support have already been compiled.

What is the best way to go about editing all of those to use $\LaTeX$ for properly formatted math? **I suppose that we will not want to edit them all right away**, because that will drown out any new questions appearing on the frontpage. Are we going to be editing them slowly, one per day or something like that? Or all at once anyway?

Comment: @DouglasDaseeco I don't think stackexchange sites really have any functionality for those kinds of announcements, other than meta posts (which most users of the main site won't see). Its use will slowly grow as more and more people see it being used in other posts though. I personally try to remember to edit about one old post per day from the lists that were compiled in the original meta discussion (not more because we don't want to flood the front page with old questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on individual inclination, however

- Restricting edits to just a few per day would be optimal