# What should we do about programming resource recommendation questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm noticing that we get quite a few questions asking for recommendations of programming languages or libraries. Unfortunately, I'm not sure that wordsmithing our site description or help center will make it sufficiently clear that such recommendations are off-topic (both because of site scope and the fact that recommendations go out of date fast). Not everyone reads the help center's [on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); I don't even see a direct link to it from the asking form.

We can keep closing these questions - it feels like we've handled at least a dozen so far - but it would be a better experience for new users if there was something we could point them to. We've [discussed having a collection of links to such resources](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1074/75) before, and it was correctly noted that this site isn't focused on programming anyway. Nevertheless, with a site name like "Artificial Intelligence", it's understandable that people will ask how to start AI-related projects.

What, if anything, should we do about this?

Comment: We can consider creating a wiki page either on the main site or in meta with some resources, pointing to some books or Coursera courses.

Comment: It's better to create a wiki page on the main site,so that even new users or visitors can easily be informed straight away.

Comment: @quintumnia That could be a good solution; I'd be on board with it. Would you like to write an answer here so people can vote on it?

Comment: @BenN ,basing on my analysis;why is that some questions have up-votes and no answers.Could this mean that voters understand the questions and can't even answer them!

Comment: If I could downvote this question or better this website, I would honestly. Not allowing this website discussing about AI programming tools (not problems) it's completely a waste! Stack Overflow is plenty of incompetent people and it seems that in this website is no different.

Comment: @nbro Indeed, Q&A on tools is an important thing to have, and it can be had at [datascience.se]; requests for tool suggestions can be posted at [softwarerecs.se]. If you have a specific concern about site policy (either of this site or another), I encourage you to post a constructive meta question so we can make things better.

Comment: @BenN Let me tell you just briefly here, because I think a constructive discussion on this website would not lead anywhere, since I know the most common type of person in this websites, who are closed-minded to certain aspects of certain things. Anyway, regarding this website, so far, looking at the qualities of the questions and answers, I don't think this will help improve the field of AI. They all seem opinion or philosophical-based. Everyone with a brain can philosophize. I think this website should be closed. I've read that this should be a "scientific" website. Pls, don't make me laugh.

Answer (score 7):

## Place something like what [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour) has in the tour.

Android Enthusiasts has a line in their tour:

> Have a programming question? Visit our sister site, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence).

We could put something like that in *our* tour.