# It always displays "You can only post once every 40 minutes" when I ask a question

Tags: support, asking-questions

I am trying to post a question in [the Ask Question form](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), but it always shows "You can only post once every 40 minutes" even though it's my first question.

My question is **What are the artificial intelligence frameworks?**

May I ask this question?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Mithrandir, this is a network-wide measure that applies to all users with less than 125 reputation. Source: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/295684). It's designed to slow down spammers. Once the 40-minute window elapses, you'll be able to post another question anywhere on the network. I see that you have [already done so](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2471/75).

Please note that resource recommendations are off-topic here for two reasons. First, this site is for social and conceptual questions about artificial intelligence. Also (and this applies to most sites on Stack Exchange), collections of off-site resources tend to go out of date very quickly; it takes [a community effort](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1267/75) to keep such a resource up to date. If the [scope of the site](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is unclear, please bring up your concern here on meta so we can get it clarified.

Answer (score 2):

This applies site-wide.

If you have asked a question *anywhere on the Stack Exchange network* in the past 40 minutes, you have to wait before asking a question on *any site*.

See this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322157/arent-new-users-throttled-asking-questions-anymore/322265#322265