# What kind of implementation questions should be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

It was [suggested](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/72/8) that:

> "implementation problems" be explicitly listed as outside the scope of this site

Can we clarify what this could mean? Some example would be useful.

---

[@InquisitiveLurker](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/what-should-be-on-topic-modelling-or-implementation-or-anything-else#comment1065_1078) suggested that this could mean asking about inner workings of basic algorithms, but then how we define 'inner working'.

This also may help: [How to distinguish AI modeling from implementation?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1297/8)

---

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Personally I disagree with the entire premise that "implementation should be off topic".  I don't see any point in talking nothing but theory and never talking implementation.  My fear is that that will lead us into fringe-land with a lot of sketch posts asking philosophical questions that aren't really helpful to anybody.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation problems may refer to the "how to do X with the Y tool/framework" kind of questions. Such kind of questions are indirectly related to AI, via the X part, which could lead to ask the OP to change the question focus. So questions that solely pertain to Y should be off-topic.

One issue with this approach, is that, say, 10 years ago, Y would have been seen as AI from science fictions. At some point in time, "we did it", and Y just looks like another tool.